# Getting Atata working with Microsoft Edge (Chromium)

Tags: c#, automated-tests, ui-automation, atata

It appears that the version of Selenium included with Atata does not support the EdgeOption "UseChromium", and when I try to use the Edge Driver, the test run fails unless I rename the driver in the bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\drivers\edge\91.0.864.41 folder from "msedgedriver.exe" to "MicrosoftWebDriver.exe", which leads me to believe it's trying to run the old non-chromium Edge - is there some way to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use Chromium Edge with Atata:

1. Update `Selenium.WebDriver` package to `4.0.0-beta2` version.
2. Change Atata configuration to:

   ```
   AtataContext.GlobalConfiguration
       .UseDriver(() =>
       {
           EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions
           {
               UseChromium = true
           };

           // Headless options:
           //options.AddArguments("headless", "disable-gpu", "window-size=1024,768");

           return new EdgeDriver(options);
       })
   ```

[Atata Samples / Using Headless Edge](https://github.com/atata-framework/atata-samples/tree/master/HeadlessEdge) sample might also help.